# reportlab: setting colspan for td in rml

Tags: python, reportlab, rml

I can't find any option, that would allow to set `colspan` for `td` element in `rml`. Is that somehow possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal ReportLab way to do this would be to instead use Platypus and the `Table` flowable.  When you set the style of the `Table`, you can specify a `'SPAN'` command that will bundle any rectangular area of cells into one.  You'll find more information on this in the [ReportLab User Guide](http://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf), chapter 7, page 81.

If you must use RML, I'm inclined to think that colspan is simply not available.  It's at least not in the [ReportLab RML reference document](http://www.reportlab.com/docs/rml2pdf-userguide.pdf).  Instead I think you are supposed to use `blockSpan` elements.  There's no example given, but you'll find it in [the RML manual](http://www.reportlab.com/docs/rml2pdf-userguide.pdf).

Comment: Not so perfect guideline to crack solution as Don Kirkby mentioned

Answer (score 9):

Gordon's suggestion of the `blockSpan` element worked for me. Here's an example of how to use it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<document filename="test.pdf">
  <template pageSize="(612,792)" title="Test" author="Don Kirkby">
    <pageTemplate id="first">
      <frame id="first" x1="10.0" y1="10.0" width="592" height="772"/>
    </pageTemplate>
  </template>
  <stylesheet>
    <blockTableStyle id="main">
      <blockSpan start="0,1" stop="1,1"/>
    </blockTableStyle>
  </stylesheet>
  <images/>
  <story>
    <blockTable colWidths="100.0,287.5,187.5" style="main">
      <tr>
        <td><para>Cell 0,0</para></td>
        <td><para>Cell 1,0</para></td>
        <td><para>Cell 2,0</para></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><para>Cell 0,1 will flow into its neighbour</para></td>
        <td><para>Cell 1,1 will not appear, but must be present</para></td>
        <td><para>Cell 2,1</para></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><para>Cell 0,2</para></td>
        <td><para>Cell 1,2</para></td>
        <td><para>Cell 2,2</para></td>
      </tr>
    </blockTable>
  </story>
</document>
```

Comment: Most useful solution, need to understand  <blockSpan start="0,0" stop="1,1"/> Merge First two column, <blockSpan start="0,2" stop="1,2"/> merge last raw with fist and second column.